# Navigation Bar has extra space on the right side

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I am currently creating my first website and I created a navigation bar. But I have noticed that there is some extra space on the right side of the bar. So when I highlight over the last thing on my bar there is a little bit of space that does not change colors (when I hover over things on the tab it changes the background color). So I was wondering if anyone has a solution to this problem?

```css
ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "CopperPlate", Times, serif;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1A1B1F;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity: .95;
    width: 742px;
}

ul.tab li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul.tab a {
    display: block;
    color: #E7E8EC;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 64px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .3s;
}



.home:hover {
  background-color: #0EB323;
}

.about:hover {
  background-color: #0EB323;
}

.projects:hover {
  background-color: #0EB323;
}

.contact:hover {
  background-color: #0EB323;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(34, 43, 47, .8);
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #0EB323}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<title> Website </title>

<head> 

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "CSScode.css">

<script src = "JavaScript.js"></script>
  
<style>
</style>

</head>

<body>

<ul class = "tab">
  <li><a class = "home" href = "HomePage.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class = "about" href = "#about"> About </a></li>

  <li class = "dropdown">
    <a class = "projects dropbtn"> Projects </a>
    <div class = "dropdown-content">
      <a href="#"> Project 1 </a>
      <a href="#"> Project 2 </a>
      <a href="#"> Project 3 </a>
    </div>

  <li><a class = "contact" href = "ContactPage.html"> Contact </a></li>
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give flexbox a try.
`display: flex` on the `ul`, and `flex: 1` on the `li`:

To align the `dropdown` menu with the button, `relative position` the button, 100% width on the dropdown div, and remove `overflow hidden` from the `ul`

Also, you don't need to add left and right padding to the `a` elements because you display them as block.

```css
ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "CopperPlate", Times, serif;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    background-color: #1A1B1F;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity: .95;
    width: 742px;
  
  display: flex;
  
}

ul.tab li {
  flex: 1;
    /*float: left;*/
    padding: 0px;
}

ul.tab a {
    display: block;
    color: #E7E8EC;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .3s;
}



.home:hover {
  background-color: #0EB323;
}

.about:hover {
  background-color: #0EB323;
}

.projects:hover {
  background-color: #0EB323;
}

.contact:hover {
  background-color: #0EB323;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(34, 43, 47, .8);
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #0EB323}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<title> Website </title>

<head> 

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "CSScode.css">

<script src = "JavaScript.js"></script>
  
<style>
</style>

</head>

<body>

<ul class = "tab">
  <li><a class = "home" href = "HomePage.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class = "about" href = "#about"> About </a></li>

  <li class = "dropdown">
    <a class = "projects dropbtn"> Projects </a>
    <div class = "dropdown-content">
      <a href="#"> Project 1 </a>
      <a href="#"> Project 2 </a>
      <a href="#"> Project 3 </a>
    </div>

  <li><a class = "contact" href = "ContactPage.html"> Contact </a></li>
</ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've set the width of your nav bar to 742px. The combined width of all your items (your li's) doesn't add up enough to fill the whole bar.

Try:

```
ul.tab li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 25%;
}
```

4 items at 25% total 100% of the container.

Answer (score 0):

The width of the nav bar is greater than the width of then nav items. Unless you declare a hard width on the items that adds up to the same as the width of the nav bar, you shouldn't use a fixed width.

What I would do is change `ul.tab` to be `display:inline-block;` so that it will only take up as much space as needed and will shrink to match the size of it's direct descendents, and add `text-align: center;` to that element's parent (`body` in this case) to center the element.

Here's a demo - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JEdywM

Comment: Is there a better way to line up the drop down bar and the navigation bar?

Comment: @Lukie I'm not sure what you mean by "line up the drop down bar and navigation bar" - can you elaborate?

Comment: Well when you hover over "Projects", a bar drops down and it shows 3 projects. I want the bar that drops down to be perfectly aligned with the "Projects" tab. You can see what I mean if you run the code snippet and put your mouse over "Projects". Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Lukie it seems to align for me - does it not look like this to you? http://i.imgur.com/0TH3rnO.png

Comment: For me the drop bar is little bit too far to the right. https://gyazo.com/af24a5c768f75145cc76a31d9a649f58

Comment: @Lukie what browser and OS are you using? The text-align doesn't match what I see, either.

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 and using Google Chrome.

Comment: I just tried it on my macbook on safari and it worked fine. I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 0):

Your `li` elements all have dynamic widths which are rendered as float values for the pixels and eventually rounded to full pixels. That's where that margin comes from. To prevent that:

In the CSS rule for `ul.tab` remove the width setting alltogether and add `display: inline-block;`.

PLUS: Wrap the `ul` in a container div which has `text-align: center`:

(view the snippet in full page mode to see the result)

```css
.listcontainer {
  text-align: center;
  }
ul.tab {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: "CopperPlate", Times, serif;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #1A1B1F;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    opacity: .95;
    display: inline-block;

}

ul.tab li {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
}

ul.tab a {
    display: block;
    color: #E7E8EC;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 16px 64px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: .3s;
}



.home:hover {
  background-color: #0EB323;
}

.about:hover {
  background-color: #0EB323;
}

.projects:hover {
  background-color: #0EB323;
}

.contact:hover {
  background-color: #0EB323;
}
li.dropdown {
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(34, 43, 47, .8);
    width: 200px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #0EB323}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<title> Website </title>

<head> 

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "CSScode.css">

<script src = "JavaScript.js"></script>
  
<style>
</style>

</head>

<body>
<div class="listcontainer">
<ul class = "tab">
  <li><a class = "home" href = "HomePage.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a class = "about" href = "#about"> About </a></li>

  <li class = "dropdown">
    <a class = "projects dropbtn"> Projects </a>
    <div class = "dropdown-content">
      <a href="#"> Project 1 </a>
      <a href="#"> Project 2 </a>
      <a href="#"> Project 3 </a>
    </div>

  <li><a class = "contact" href = "ContactPage.html"> Contact </a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: please note my edited answer - i hadn't seen the centering on the before, which I added now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it may help.

```
*body {
    overflow-x :hidden;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).